# Big query stored procedure error with table name as a parameter

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a stored procedure as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `myapp.dataset.count_data`(table_name STRING, start_date DATE)
BEGIN
  CREATE TEMP TABLE distinct_values AS (
    SELECT *, LAST_VALUE(v ignore NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY id) as last_v FROM `"||table_name||"`
  );
...
```

But when I call it, I get the error, `Invalid value: Table ""||table_name||"" must be qualified with a dataset (e.g. dataset.table).`

I am calling the procedure as follows, and in the call I qualify the table name:

```
CALL `myapp.dataset.compute_stats`(
  'myapp.dataset.first_sampling',
  DATE(2021,1,1)
)
```

What is the correct syntax to pass table names as parameters?

Comment: Table name can't be parameterized, so you might want to consider a dynamic query in your stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jaytiger mentioned table names cannot be parameterized, Consider below query as I used execute immediate to run the query dynamically.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE `myProject.myDataset.myProcedure`(table_name STRING, start_date DATE)
BEGIN
DECLARE table_name STRING DEFAULT NULL;
SET table_name = `table_name`;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE format("""
  CREATE TEMP TABLE distinct_values AS (
    SELECT *, LAST_VALUE(v ignore NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY id) as last_v FROM %s
  );
""", table_name);
END
```

I tried evoking the procedure below:

```
DECLARE table_name STRING DEFAULT NULL;
DECLARE start_date DATE DEFAULT NULL;
set table_name = "myDataset.SampleTable";
CALL `myProject.myDataset.myProcedure`(table_name, start_date);
```

I successfully called the procedure (My sample table is empty, so it will show no data.)
[image]